# How does Eggsy become so efficient in fight?

Tags: kingsman-the-secret-service

The first half of the movie, Eggsy (the main character) doesn't seem good in fighting. We don't see him really fight but he certainly doesn't seem that good.

He gets bullied by his father in law even when he is alone with him (when the father is with all his friends, it makes sense not to do anything at 1 vs 5-6).

I understand he might have had some training during the "interview" process but when he goes to save the world, he has become a real machine. And the interview process doesn't last for more than few weeks at best.

So how can he become this good in such a short time?

And also, the last contestant who got eliminated from the interview, doesn't seem like he can fight in the last scenes.

Comment: Do you really think the dogs go from puppies to fully grown in "a few weeks"? It's probably been at least 6 months to a year.

Comment: I would be suprised if this kind of dog wouldn't grow up really quickly in like 2-3 months max.

Comment: **All** of the dogs grow up... Roxy's dog (a poodle, I think it was) would not grow up that quickly. Large dogs take time to grow. I think you've just got the timeline wrong because the film compresses time in an odd way.

Comment: Eggsy's dog is a pug.  It would be about 18 months old in the scenes where it was grown.

Comment: I have a problem with this as well. They never show him as a capable fighter until the very end. The original lancelot was no match for gazelle but after a few months of training she is no match for Eggsy? I agree that a suspension of disbelief is necessary for these types of movies, however this is not a minor detail. The entire plot is about Eggsy's growth into a badass spy, and they don't show it. one minute he is a punk kid getting bullied and the next he is a super spy. this is lazy screenwriting imo.

Comment: @user23048: Lancelot was not a match, after he got attacked from behind, without being able to prepare.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a combination of a few things.

1. Harry periodically drops comments about how his background and how talented Eggsy is: high IQ, possible Olympic caliber gymnast, high weapons scores, some Royal Marine training, etc.
2. The training scenes suggest a lot of training that isn't explicitly shown.  Obviously they were trained as snipers as suggested in the one scene with Charlie as a spotter.   Merlin also mentions they were taught [neuro-linguistic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuro-linguistic_programming) before the seduction test.  It is safe to assume there was a lot of combat training that wasn't shown.
3. Suspension of disbelief.   The movie is a goofy love-letter to old James Bond films so realism takes a backseat to entertaining.  If we are willing to accept that Harry can stab someone to death with a pistol frame, then we can make the leap that Eggsy became very dangerous due to his training.  :)

Comment: I'd add that the movie clearly has implied that training took a long time (one clear example, Galahad is in a coma for long enough to grow a serious beard and that is just one clear indicator of skipped time). And Eggsy was already well trained as a marine before he started and as a gymnast. So you don't need to suspend disbelief *that* much.

Comment: @matt_black I beg to differ, even just a little bit. :) http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--xIffKZ7p--/ulnxnfzdyaz7egmuzjhr.gif

Comment: @matt_black: To add to that, when he stole the cab (after not shooting the dog), he went after his father in law, which would seem to indicate he's more confident in fighting.

Answer (score 2):

If you pay attention to eggsys little sister when she's crying in the play pen she looks like she's at least 4-6 months old then when he goes back home after he finishes his training and sees her again she looks at least 2 years old